# Is there a C signal-cli using libsignal-protocol-c lib

Tags: c, signals, protocols

I am doing a POC on using signal with arm target. I have found signal-cli for Desktop which is using java .But I am looking for client code which is written in C. Is there any client code for signal which is using libsignal-protocol-c?
https://github.com/AsamK/signal-cli

Comment: are you talking about POSIX signals? if yes, what is the link with protocol and java?

Comment: No , I am taking about signalapp which is kind of messaging protocol. Above is the link for java client. There is c lib for it libsignal-protocol-c but no examples are provided how to use those lib apis to write application.

Comment: Got any further on this? I in the same boat... want to run it on openwrt, but java ... sigh (to big for my taste).

Comment: @Roger Did you get any luck on this? I'm in the same boat -- The signal Documentation is kind of rubbish insofar as getting a person started, and I don't feel like downloading Java.

Comment: @anon unfortunately I did not. I ended up using the java version. I feel overweight  :/